# XAML intellisense not working for <StaticResource/>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, intellisense, staticresource

I'm writing XAML/WPF and sometimes use object-element syntax to reference a static resource:

```
<StaticResource ResourceKey="theResourceKey"/>
```

This seems consistent with the [StaticResource Markup Extension docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and is the only option I know of in some cases, e.g.:

```
<Transform3DGroup>
    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0.5" OffsetY="0.5"/>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="PlateScaleTransform"/>
</Transform3DGroup>
```

The problem is, I get no intellisense suggesting `<StaticResource`, but once I've typed it I *do* get intellisense suggesting `ResourceKey=""`. Anyone have ideas why the former intellisense suggestion isn't working?

Comment: Report bugs to Microsoft. In recent versions of Visual Studio, you have a button for that at the top right of the window. Ensure that you have the latest version and that it is up-to-date.

Comment: Definitely will do, if this is a bug. Just want to make sure it's not a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been long enough, I'm convinced it's a bug/omission. People can up-vote the problem report via the "Report a Problem" tool:

[image]

Search for "No Intellisense for StaticResource", and there is a submission to up-vote:

[image]